# Как автоматически задержать публикацию всех(каждого) постов на час,день,неделю?

Tags: wordpress

Мне необходимо задержать все публикующиеся записи на определенное время.

```
$time += 5400; 
$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
    'post_date'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time),
      'post_status'  => 'future' ); 
    $my_post->edit_date = true;

wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Но по каким то причинам это не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код который я искал

```
 $number_tesla = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'erf', true);
$time = time();
 if (!$number_tesla){
 $number_tesla =gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time + 60 );
 update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'erf', $number_tesla);
  $my_post = array(
  'edit_date'   => true,
  'post_date'    => $number_tesla,
  'post_status'  => 'future' ,
  'post_date_gmt' => $number_tesla,
  'ID'           => get_the_ID()
  );   
wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

Если вдруг кому-то он понадобится